# Webcam problem with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: webcam

I'm having trouble with my integrated webcam. While I open the webcam software `cheese`, the webcam shows a black image.

The output of `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e004 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:643f Microdia Dell Integrated HD Webcam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro Usb Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:070f Microsoft Corp. LifeChat LX-3000 Headset
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The output of `cat /proc/version` is:

```
Linux version 5.4.0-31-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-059) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)) #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 20:20:34 UTC 2020
```

What can I do?